# what is a difference between Clustered Index and Unique Index?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I am just learning about Indexing in SQL server but got confuse between Clustered and Unique index. if both are applied on a unique key column ex: PersonID. so what is difference between both.

Thanx.

Comment: Basically, being [clustered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190639.aspx) and being [unique](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187019.aspx) are two distinct and independent characteristics of an index.

Comment: @Andriy M - you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Jeff O: Thanks. That wouldn't satisfy the OP's ultimate request, and I couldn't trust myself with a more complete answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A unique index is just an index with a unique constraint, nothing more, nothing less. A clustered index orders the data phsyically on the disk to match the index. It is useful if you access the data in the table very often via just one column, e.g. via the primary key. Also a table can have only one clustered index (obvious, of course).

Comment: Thanx, what you mean by clustered index sort data physically on the disk?

Comment: When you insert data to a table, there is normally no specific order. It just gets inserted somewhere. When you have a clustered index, the data on the disk is ordered by the key you create the clustered index with. e. g. you have a table with an integer field ifield and create a clustered index over it. Then the data on the disk will be ordered ascending by the integer field ifield. First comes record with ifield=1, then record with ifield=2, etc, pp

Comment: Thanks once again, but have one more question on this, every table by default has a clustered index when we define any primary key in it? or we have to create it.

Comment: No, by default there is no clustered index. Clustered indexes have wide consequences. Every UPDATE, INSERT or DELETE statement could get VERY slow because the DBMS has to re-order the table physically on disk. Only use clustered indexes if you really need them or if you are sure that UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT are very rare.

Comment: The pk is by default a Clustered index in SQL server.

Comment: Oh? Since when? Our SQL server 2000 doesn't do this.

Comment: @gbn this is new for me. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Data in a clustered index is not "physically sorted" on disk. Data is stored in pages which are frequently (but not necessarily) written to disk in the order they are allocated, irrespective of the data on them. Clustered index pages are ordered by a doubly linked list of pointers between pages in exactly the same way as nonclustered indexes are.

Comment: @ckruse: when you say "A unique index is just an index with a unique constraint..", do you mean "a non-clustured index with unique constraint"? Also, does it mean that duplicate value can't be entered in that column?

Answer (score 44):

The two are unrelated:

- "Unique" ensures each value occurs *exactly* once only
- "Clustered" is how the data is arranged on disk

You can have all 4 permutations:

- "unique non-clustered"
- "unique clustered"
- "non-unique non-clustered"
- "non-unique clustered"

Some confusion occurs because the default for a "primary key" (PK) in SQL Server is clustered.

A "primary key" must always be unique though. The difference between "unique" and "PK" is that unique allows one NULL, PK doesn't allow any NULLs.

Finally, some number limits

- because clustered refers to the on disk layout, you can have only one clustered index per table
- a table can't have more than one pimary key but can have many unique indexes

Comment: @iMatoria: yes with 2 notes: 1. By default in SQL Server, a PK will be clustered. 2. A PK does not allow NULLs, a "unique clustered" allows one

Comment: Considering that, PK doesn't fall in any of the above mentioned 4 permutations? OR is it that there is 2 more permutation: 1. clustured. 2. non-clustured. Sorry, if i am missing something and been already mentioned by you.

Comment: @iMatoria: When you create a primary key (CREATE/ALTER TABLE) or an index (CREATE INDEX) you can mention CLUSTERED or NONCLUSTERED (there is no 3rd option). If you don't mention it, it will default to CLUSTERED for a PK, NONCLUSTERED for an index. So basically, yes, a PK is "unique clustered": I was trying to explain why this is so, sorry. Sometimes (not very often) you'll find a NONCLUSTERED PK with some another CLUSTERED index works better for your queries

Comment: awesome, thats perfect explanation. Up vote for that. If i had to summarize your previous 2 comments regarding PK, than it would be: PK is "unique clustered" index with extra thing of not allowing NULL values, which is how PK is different from Unique key in simple terms. Thanks anyways.

Comment: there is one more difference between PK and UQ i.e you can declare only one PK in a table where as you can declare more than one UQ in a table

Comment: give an example for non-unique non clustered index.

Answer (score 10):

One crude way of thinking about it is to think of a phone book. The clustered index is the order the pages are written in. Any other indexes are separate lists showing which page to go.

For example a phone book is “clustered” on surname but you might also want to lookup by street so you would have a separate list saying people that live on fake street are on pages 3,45 and 63 etc

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK every table can have just one clustered index that is the primary key usually, but it may have m any unique indexes.

More: http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/07/04/back-to-the-basics-difference-between-primary-key-and-unique-index/